# PHP Ajax jQuery Post - What have I done wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

This is my jQuery...

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://adamscarter.co.uk/daily/facebook/savefbprofile.php',
                data: {'fb_id': fb_id, 'fbusername': fbusername, 'location_id': location_id, 'gender': gender},
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log('Before send: ' + fb_id, fbusername, location_id, gender);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('saveFbProfile post ajax success');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

...and this is my PHP...

```
<?php
session_start();

include('dbcon.php');

$gender = substr($_POST['gender'], 0, 1);
$fb_id = $_POST['fb_id'];
$location_id = $_POST['location_id'];
$fbusername = $_POST['fbusername'];

//Set session vars
$_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
$_SESSION['fb_id'] = $fb_id;
$_SESSION['location_id'] = $location_id;
$_SESSION['fbusername'] = $fbusername;

if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    mysql_select_db('users', $GLOBALS['conInsert']);
    $sql = "UPDATE user_fb_details SET gender = '". $gender. "', fb_id = '". $fb_id. "', location_id = '". $location_id. "', username = '". $fbusername. "' WHERE user_id = '". $_SESSION['userid']. "'";
    mysql_query($sql, $GLOBALS['conInsert']);
}
?>
```

Is there a mistake in my code? When I log the variables they all have the correct value, but i just get a 'parseerror'.

Comment: Do you have actual error or is 'parseerror' what you're getting? Where are you seeing the error? Go into Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug and watch the AJAX request.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been a bit more specific `<script type="text/javascript">
//AJAX EVENT SCRIPT
//Setup default AJAX method
$.ajaxSetup({
 async: true,
 dataType: "xml",
 cache: false,
 error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log(textStatus);
 },
 global: true,
 ifModified: false,
 processData: true,
 type: 'GET'
});
</script>` basically, I set it up so when there is an error, the textStatus is logged to the console. I'm using Chrome Dev tools btw.

Comment: Do you know where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: You should take more care in sanitizing your $_POST variables before posting them to your database.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like jQuery might be trying to parse the result of the POST as a JSON response and failing as it's not JSON. You might want to set the [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax#data-types) to `'text'`, or return a different `Content-Type` from the PHP.

And you'll definitely want to fix your dangerous SQL-injection holes with a bit of `mysql_real_escape_string` or parameterised queries.

Comment: thanks both for the 'sql-injection holes' help, I am aware of these and this was just a case of building the core version and doing security features later on :)

Comment: Thanks! Just tried changing the dataType to 'text' and it works perfectly :)